# How can I choose two different rows of a DataFrame and have them in a new DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

What is simplest way to choose two different rows of a dataframe?

`tx_df` is the original dataset, and `toy_df` is the subset which is supposed to contain only two rows of the original dataset.

```
toy_df = tx_df.loc[tx_df['CustomerID'] == (14566) ]
toy_df = tx_df.loc[tx_df['CustomerID'] == (17844) ]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tx_df.set_index('CustomerID').loc[[14566, 17844]]
tx_df[tx_df.CustomerID.isin([14566, 17844])]
tx_df.query('CustomerID == 14566 or CusromerID == 17844')
```

P.S. I think that in this case the easiest way to locate records by `CustomerID` would be to use the latter as an index (see the first line in the code above).

Comment: I knew about toy_df = tx_df[tx_df['CustomerID'].isin([14566, 17844])], but I wanted to use the equal sign instead. So I love what you said in your last line. Thank you @ Vitalizzare

Answer (score 1):

Using [.query](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

```
toy_df = tx_df.query("CustomerID.isin([14566, 17844])")
```

Comment: Like that, Jason! Thank you